# How to save url using xdotool ctrl+c data in python list in linux

Tags: python, linux, url, clipboard, pyperclip

I started with following code

```
def getclip(self):
   xdo = Xdo()
   key = "ctrl+c"
   xdo.send_keysequence_window(0, key.encode())
```

now i wish to print the data in clipboard(literally - not the python module) in python console

how can I achieve that?

Comment: Why not using existing module like https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/ ?

Comment: this really helps, thanks @Ôrel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xdo = Xdo()

def sendkeys(*keys):
    for k in keys: xdo.send_keysequence_window(0, k.encode())

def geturl():
    sendkeys("alt+d")
    sendkeys("ctrl+c")
    url=pyperclip.paste()
```